# I keep getting signed out

Tags: xbox-network

Whenever I sign into my profile I get a notification pops up says "signed out from another console."

I'm only connected on two xbox's, mine and my dad's. I've asked my friend to see if the "person" signed in as me is playing anything, but it just says that I'm at the home screen.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: You can only be signed into one pregen console at a time.

Comment: Xbox one and 360 you can sign into each at the same time but not two Xbox360 or two XboxOne. Only one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

You can only be logged in on one console at a time for each account. If someone else signs in on another console, then the currently signed in console is automatically logged out so that the other person can sign in under that same account on a different console.